# how to update the widget with alarm manager for every 45 minutes in android

Tags: android

iam working on a project where i need to update appWidget with alarm manager for every 45 minutes. I know how to create a widget with out using alarmmanager but i need my widget to update using alarm manager. could any one help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context, int minuts, Class widgetService)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, widgetService);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * minuts, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }
```